# lombok annotation @SneakyThrows

Tags: java, lombok

I have question about @SneakyThrows can be used to sneakily throw checked exceptions without actually declaring this in your method's throws clause.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private void throwE() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void t() {
        throwE();
    }
}
```

Here is generate by lombok.

```
public class Demo {
    public Demo() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    }

    private void throwE() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    }

    private void t() {
        try {
            this.throwE();
        } catch (Throwable var2) {
            throw var2;
        }
    }
}
```

Why the code generate by lombok can fakes out the compiler without declaring throws clause.

Answer (score 8):

See [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows), it uses `Lombok.sneakyThrow(t)` and not `var2`:

> ```
> public void run() {
>     try {
>       throw new Throwable();
>     } catch (Throwable t) {
>       throw Lombok.sneakyThrow(t);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code  `throw var2` is decompile by devtool and i believe it's generate lombok plugin.Obviously it's different from code `throw Lombok.sneakyThrow(t)`.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is that Lombok cheats the compiler - but what you've shown is a decompiled version of the compiled byte code - and the JVM running the byte code does not distinguish between checked and unchecked exceptions: it does not care.

If you take a look at [`Lombok.sneakyThrow()`](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/Lombok.java#L49) source code, you'll see that it eventually does two things:

1. A null check
2. A cast

Both are removed as part of the compilation, which is why your decompiled code simply rethrows the exception.